# Getting variables outside a bracket and adding it into the variables inside the bracket

Tags: javascript

i am currently doing a random minterm maxterm mini program.

```
    var totalvar = getRandomInt(3,5);

    var main = "";
    for (var i = 1; i <= totalvar; i++) {
        var test =  getRandomInt(1,4);
        //alert(test);
        var myArray = ["A","B","C","D","A&apos;","B&apos;","C&apos;","D&apos;"];
        var text ="";
        for (var a = 1; a <= test; a++) {
                    function random(array) {
                    return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)]
                    }
                        var testing = random(myArray);
                        if (testing =="A") {
                            var testing2 ="A&apos;";    

                        } else if (testing =="A&apos;") {
                            var testing2 ="A";  

                        } else if (testing =="B") {
                            var testing2 ="B&apos;";    

                        } else if (testing =="B&apos;") {
                            var testing2 ="B";  

                        }else if (testing =="C") {
                            var testing2 ="C&apos;";    

                        } else if (testing =="C&apos;") {
                            var testing2 ="C";  

                        }else if (testing =="D") {
                            var testing2 ="D&apos;";    

                        } else if (testing =="D&apos;") {
                            var testing2 ="D";  

                        }
                        //alert(testing);
                        //alert(myArray);
                        text += testing
                        var index = myArray.indexOf(testing);
                        if (index > -1) {
                            myArray.splice(index, 1);
                        }
                        var index = myArray.indexOf(testing2);
                        if (index > -1) {
                            myArray.splice(index, 1);
                        }

        }

        var impt = totalvar - i;
                        var frontbracket = main.split("(").length;
            var backbracket = main.split(")").length;
        if (impt >= 2) {

            var brackets =  getRandomInt(1,3);
            var chances =  getRandomInt(1,3);
            var chances1 =  getRandomInt(1,3);
            var lastLetter = main.charAt(main.length - 1);


            alert(frontbracket);
            alert(backbracket);
            if (frontbracket == backbracket) {
            if (brackets == 1) {
             text = "(" + text;

            if (main == "") {
             main = text;


         }else
         main += "+" + text;



         } else {
             if (main == "") {
             main = text;
         }   else if ( lastLetter == ')') {
                    if ( chances !== 1) {
                        main += text;

                    }else
                        main += "+" + text;


            }else
                main += "+" + text;


         }
    }
         else if (frontbracket != backbracket){
         text = text + ")";
                main += "+" + text;


         }


        }    else if (frontbracket != backbracket){
         text = text + ")";
                main += "+" + text;


         }
                 else {
            var brackets =  getRandomInt(1,3);
            var chances =  getRandomInt(1,3);
        var lastLetter = main.charAt(main.length - 1);

        if (brackets == 1) {
             text = "(" + text + ")";

         if (main == "") {
             main = text;
         }  else if ( lastLetter == ')') {
         if ( chances !== '1') {
             main += text;

         }else
            main += "+" + text;


         }else
         main += "+" + text;



         } else {
             if (main == "") {
             main = text;
         }   else if ( lastLetter == ')') {
                    if ( chances !== 1) {
                        main += text;

                    }else
                        main += "+" + text;


            }else
                main += "+" + text;


         }
    }   

    }
```

Currently i am trying to create random questions like

1. (ABC+C'D'A')C+C'B'
2. BAC'D'+(CB'A'D)(B'A)
3. BCA+(B'C)(A'C')
4. (BC'D'A+CADB')A'DC'+B'+(D'A')
5. (BC'D'A+CADB')+B'+(D'A')

So based on this 4 questions, i can solve qn 2, qn 3, qn 5 by using the replace function but for qn1 and qn4,
i have to check if there is a plus sign inside the bracket and if there are variables outside the bracket, i will need to add the variables inside.
If there are no variables outside of the bracket like Qn5, i will just remove the brackets.

like this qn5

5. BC'D'A+CADB'+B'+D'A'

For example qn4 should look like this after the function is done with it

1. BC'D'AA'DC'+CADB'A'DC'+B'+D'A'

May i ask for some advice regarding this please?
on a function that checks whether there is a plus sign inside the bracket then check whether there are any variables directly outside the bracket and if there is, the variable outside must be added to the variables inside the bracket

Comment: For future reference, you can use a switch statement to help your code look a little cleaner (at least, look cleaner in many people's opinions)

Comment: just another hint, please declare all variable on top first.